# How to backtest a factor by building a factor-tilting portfolio

Tags: backtesting, factor-models

A recent research paper from Wolfe Research suggests an alternative to the traditional "long top quintile, short bottom quintile " approach to backtesting a factor.  It says to

> construct a factor tilting portfolio, where a long-only portfolio with exposures to a given factor can be built with a target tracking error.

How would this even work?  Tracking error to what?  I know the paper isn't referring to "factor mimicking portfolios" because that's presented as a different alternative to long-short backtesting.

Comment: Can you provide a link or the title/authors of the paper.

Comment: @RRG No, unfortunately it's confidential broker stuff:  there are big red letters up top saying "do not forward" and the email address of the guy who forwarded it to me.

Comment: As with a lot of broker quant research, there are good ideas but they've skimmed over the maths a little too quickly.  I'm trying to wrap my head around it.